# I want to print from any application, and it create an email in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, print-to-pdf

I'm going to try to go paperless in 2010, and store everything in my outlook mail folders.

I realized that most of the paper I currently have is just printouts from web sites or other apps.  So I want to be able to print from any application to a printer driver that creates a an email with pdf attachment in my outlook inbox.  Then I can file that in the appropriate folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: Save trees. Eat a beaver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CutePDF Writer from [www.cutepdf.com](http://www.cutepdf.com) will write to PDF.

then right-click on the PDF and click Send to > Mail Recipient. Then send it to yourself, then file it away.

CutePDF Writer is freeware.

Question: Why file everything in Outlook and not the filesystem ?

Comment: Pretty good, although I'd rather not have to send it through the internet just to get it into outlook.  But, after testing your idea, I realized that once you hit Send to Mail Recipient, you dont acutally have to send the email.  You can just hit save, and it's in your inbox.  perfect!

The main reason I want to use outlook, is because all of my other correspondence, emailed receipts, statements are already in outlook.  Just want to keep it all in one place.

Answer (score 1):

PDFCreator is my go-to for this.  Free & open-source -- [you can find it here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/).